# Lucene - cannot query values with capital letters

Tags: lucene, case

I'd like to index and search lower-cased keywords. I attached test code which IMHO clearly demonstrates my simple goal. I index two words, one with capital letter, and then I search and print them back one by one. For this I created `Analyzer` which just converts keywords to lower-case (`KeywordAnalyzer` doesn't lower-case and `SimpleAnalyzer` splits on non-letter characters). I use this analyzer for both `IndexWriter` and `QueryParser`. However, for some reason I can't get back words with capital letters *even if I search for lower-cased word* ("bye" in the example).

Program expected output:

```
hello
Bye
```

Actual output:

```
hello
```

What's the problem?

I hope you don't mind code is in Scala. I'll gladly help you understand in case it's not clear what the code does.

```
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory
import java.io.{Reader, File}
import org.apache.lucene.index._
import org.apache.lucene.document._
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharTokenizer
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents

final class LcAnalyzer(lucVer: Version) extends Analyzer {
    def createComponents(fieldName: String, reader: Reader) =
        new TokenStreamComponents(new CharTokenizer(lucVer, reader) {
            def isTokenChar(c: Int) = true
            override def normalize(c: Int) = Character.toLowerCase(c)
        })
}

object LuceneTest {

    val LV = Version.LUCENE_43
    val F = "myf"
    val VALS = Seq("hello", "Bye")

    val indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File("testindex"))
    val anlz = new LcAnalyzer(LV)

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        writeData()
        val reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir)
        val searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader)
        val p = new QueryParser(LV, F, anlz)

        for (v <- VALS) {
            val hits = searcher.search(p.parse(F + ':' + v), 1).scoreDocs
            for (i <- 0 until hits.length) {
                val doc = searcher.doc(hits(i).doc)
                println(doc.get(F))
            }
        }
    }

    def writeData() {
        val writer = {
            val wc = new IndexWriterConfig(LV, anlz)
            val writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, wc)
            writer.commit
            writer
        }
        for (v <- VALS) {
            val doc = new Document
            doc.add(new StringField(F, v, Field.Store.YES))
            writer.addDocument(doc)
        }
        writer.commit
        writer.close
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just string together a `KeywordTokenizer` and a `LowercaseFilter` in your `LcAnalyzer.createComponents` (See the example in the [Analyzer docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html))?  I'd guess your issue is in the definition of `LcAnalyzer`, though I'm not really familiar with Scala, so can't pinpoint your exact issue.  I don't see anything obviously conceptually wrong.

Comment: I stated my reason for not using these in the beginning. Implementation of my analyzer is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: You state that you don't use KeywordAnalyzer because it doesn't lowercase.  If you tokenize with a KeywordTokenizer, and then apply a LowercaseFilter, that solves that problem.  I don't see any other statement that precludes this approach, please do clarify if there is something that was not made clear.

Comment: No it doesn't solve the problem. I've used KeywordAnalyzer before and the result was same. I actually looked at code of both mentioned Lucene analyzers and implemented my accordingly. What problems are there with my analyzer?